# MySQL: Log only drop/create commands

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to log only certain MySQL operations?

I need to enable it's log in a production server but only for drop/create commands. Unfortunately logging everything is slow and I only need these specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sophisticated way to log queries in mysql. The only thing you can do is the following:

> The general query log is a general
>   record of what mysqld is doing. The
>   server writes information to this log
>   when clients connect or disconnect,
>   and it logs each SQL statement
>   received from clients. The general
>   query log can be very useful when you
>   suspect an error in a client and want
>   to know exactly what the client sent
>   to mysqld.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: This kind of logging REALLY slows down MySQL :(

Comment: @Kedare, yeah +IO and usually mysql is IO bound anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can try having binlog turned on. it'll not hit your performance as badly as regular logs [only commands changing the data are logged]. but it might be not suitable for your needs if you for instance want to log from which ip given drop command was issued.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very pretty workaround. Just pass the `tail`'s output to `grep`, e.g. like this:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log | grep "update "
```